# parser.add_argument and parser.parse_args() with jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, argparse

I'm trying to run some code with a jupyter notebook, but from the beginning, I have issues.

Indeed, it looks like I can't use these commands:

```
parser.add_argument('--lr', default=0.1, type=float, help='learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--resume', '-r', action='store_true', help='resume from checkpoint')
```

usage: `ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--lr LR] [--resume]`
and `ipykernel_launcher.py` gives error: `unrecognized arguments: -f`

And:

```
args = parser.parse_args()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py in parse_args(self, args, namespace)
   1750         if argv:
   1751             msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
-> 1752             self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
   1753         return args
   1754 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py in error(self, message)
   2499         self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
   2500         args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
-> 2501         self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py in exit(self, status, message)
   2486         if message:
   2487             self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
-> 2488         _sys.exit(status)
   2489 
   2490     def error(self, message):

SystemExit: 2
```

I've seen that some people already had this problem when trying to use jupyter and arg_parse, but I can't find an easy solution.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tell us what you learned from other people's problems.  Are you expecting us to give you a solution that they didn't receive?

Comment: The thing is I didn’t understand the other explanations, and that’s why I had to open a new question :/

Answer (score 1):

When I launch a blank notebook and execute

```
import sys
sys.argv
```

I get

```
['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py',
 '-f',
 '/run/user/1000/jupyter/kernel-b2d72478-6aaa-4206-9bf3-38fc1a0fd303.json']
```

`parse_args()` uses the `sys.argv` list that 'normally' comes from the shell that's calling your script.  It is a list of the commandline strings.

The `sys.argv` that your script sees includes this `-f` argument, created by `jupyter`.

You could use `parse_known_args()` so that your parser doesn't raise this error.  But you that won't help you get `--lr` or `-r` arguments - because `jupyter's` own parser will reject them.

The essence of the previous SO questions is that you can't provide commandline arguments to a notebooks.

Comment: So there is no solutions in my case?? Maybe I can just say that lr = 0.1to replace the first add_argument, but for the second add_argument, I don't know what is it: '--resume', '-r', action='store_true', help='resume from checkpoint') so I don't know how to replace it !!

Comment: Just to be clear, are you running a Python script ( a `.py` file) or a notebook (.ipynb)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer: A .ipynb

Comment: Can't you just control all of that from within the notebook - once it's started?  The purpose the `jupyter notebook` command is to start the server, not to talk to or control the notebook.  The server could be running several different notebooks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you want we to do exactly??